# How to select columns that built on each other in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

how can I read entries in SQL where the column entries build on each other.
In the first column is the material number. These again consist of different materials, with their own material number in the first column.

How can I find out e.g. from material 123 the quantity of all sub-materials.

I have loaded the data from an Exeltabbele into a Panda database and then loaded this into a SQL database.

Should  I use loops in python, to iterate over the table? Or is there a smarter way?

[image]

Comment: for these type of queries you shuold use recursive queries with CTE( common table expression):